# Color the regular expression in same file

Tags: sed, text-processing, regex

I have a big file and need to look over certain patterns. and also look for another patterns based on first pattern and thus this requires to color the lines which matches the search in the same file.

The major requirement here is that I need to have those colors saved in my original text file and not just on the terminal

for example

```
line
lactose
galactose
glusocse
lactose
lactos
```

and I need to search for lactose as well as to color lactose (for example yellow)

Comment: You need something more than `grep "lactose" file`?

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. I need to have those colors in my original file. meaning it should color and save the color in file not just on terminal

Comment: I'm very sorry for having misunderstood you.  You should [edit] your question and make it more clear that you want to save the colours for later use (now that I re-read it, the title gives a slight hint, but I didn't understand it that way.)  Also, click the green check-mark turning it back to grey as my solution will never be able to save the colours, only display them.  You need a solution with `sed` in combination with ANSI colours (which I haven't read the complete manual of yet: I just know that’s the direction to take)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a script for that:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Getopt::Std;
use strict;
use Term::ANSIColor; 

my %opts;
getopts('himc:l:',\%opts);
if ($opts{h}) {
    print<<EoF; 
DESCRIPTION

$0 will highlight the given pattern in color. 

USAGE

$0 [OPTIONS] -l PATTERN FILE

If FILE is omitted, it reads from STDIN.

-c : comma separated list of colors
-h : print this help and exit
-l : comma separated list of search patterns (can be regular expressions)
-m : only print matching lines (grep-like)
-s : makes the search case sensitive

EoF
    exit(0);
}

my $case_sensitive=$opts{s}||undef;
my $only_matching=$opts{m}||undef;
my @color=('bold red','bold blue', 'bold yellow', 'bold green', 
           'bold magenta', 'bold cyan', 'yellow on_magenta', 
           'bright_white on_red', 'bright_yellow on_red', 'white on_black');
## user provided color
if ($opts{c}) {
    @color=split(/,/,$opts{c});
}
## read patterns
my @patterns;
if ($opts{l}) {
    @patterns=split(/,/,$opts{l});
} else {
    die("Need a pattern to search for (-l)\n");
}

# Setting $| to non-zero forces a flush right away and after 
# every write or print on the currently selected output channel. 
$|=1;

while (<>) {
    my $matched;
    for (my $c=0; $c<=$#patterns; $c++) {
    if ($case_sensitive) {
        if (/$patterns[$c]/) {
        s/($patterns[$c])/color("$color[$c]").$1.color("reset")/ge && $matched++; 
        }
    } else {
        if (/$patterns[$c]/i) {
        s/($patterns[$c])/color("$color[$c]").$1.color("reset")/ige && $matched++; 
        }
    }
    }
    ## Skip non-matching lines
    if ($only_matching) {
        next unless $matched;
    }

    print STDOUT;
}
```

Save the file as `~/bin/color`, make it executable (`chmod 755 ~/bin/color`) and then run it, giving it a comma-separated list of patterns to color:

### [image]

So, to color the lines of your input file, you could just use the script above, redirect the output to a new file and then rename the original:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Type the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Hit <kbd>PgDn</kbd> until you're at the end.

Copy-paste the following text:

```
alias grep-grey="GREP_COLOR='1;30' grep --color=always"
alias grep-red="GREP_COLOR='1;31' grep --color=always"
alias grep-green="GREP_COLOR='1;32' grep --color=always"
alias grep-yellow="GREP_COLOR='1;33' grep --color=always"
alias grep-blue="GREP_COLOR='1;34' grep --color=always"
alias grep-magenta="GREP_COLOR='1;35' grep --color=always"
alias grep-cyan="GREP_COLOR='1;36' grep --color=always"
alias grep-white="GREP_COLOR='1;37' grep --color=always"
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>Y</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Exit all terminals

Enter a new terminal and type:

```
grep-yellow lactose /path/to/file
```

### and stare in wonder!  ;-)

Comment: You can chain them as well like: `grep-red --ignore-case tose | grep-blue --ignore-case galac` (but no saving of colours, unfortunately)  :(